# How do I pass a numeric vector that is used as part of a function to purrr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a function that I wrote that scrapes JSON from an API and saves the result to my computer.  How would I take a numeric vector and pass it to the function to scrape each individual JSON file and save?

```
scrape_function <- function(period, api_key){

base_url <- "http://www.madeupurl.com/api/figures?"

params <- 
list(
period = period,
response_format = "JSON",
api_key = api_key)

resp <- httr::GET(base_url, params)
  # Save Response in JSON Format
  out <- httr::content(resp, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

  # Read into JSON format
  json <-
    out %>%
    jsonlite::prettify() %>% 
    jsonlite::fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE) 

  # Save Raw JSON Output
  jsonlite::write_json(json, here::here("data-raw", "json", paste0("data-", period, ".json" )))

}
```

I want to run this function for a numeric vector of periods 1 through 28.  The result will be the files as outlined in the function.  I'm not sure which `purrr` function to use, as I've only used it for `df` using `map_dfr`.

```
period <- 1:28
```

Comment: `map(1:28, ~ scrape_function(.x, api_key))` Would return the single results as elements of a list. However, I don’t know how your api_key argument looks like, above is just a placeholder.

Comment: The API Key is an object in the Global Environment and run under a separate function.

Comment: Would each value of period have a different api_key?

Comment: If your function is only causing the side-effect of writing JSON files you might consider using `walk` instead of `map`.

Comment: The api_key is the same for each period.

Comment: Then you don’t need it necessarily as an argument in your scrape_function. You can just include it in the function as a unchanging term.

Comment: Did the above command using `map` work?

Comment: Yes it did.  Thanks!  Can you respond as an answer, and I'll mark as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to loop over an integer vector is probably a `for loop`:

```
for (x in 1:28) {
 scrape_function(x, api_key)
}
```

You could translate this in a base R `lapply`:

```
lapply(1:28, function(x) {scrape_function(x, api_key)})
```

Or in a `purrr::map` call which allows the shorter lambda (~) function notation:

```
purrr::map(1:28, ~ scrape_function(.x, api_key))
```

Note that `lapply` and `map` will both produce the desired side-effect (of writing the JSON files) and a list as output. If you are only interested in the side-effects you might as well use `walk`.

```
purrr::walk(1:28, ~ scrape_function(.x, api_key))
```

`walk` not only produces side-effects, it can also return the original object which was passed into it when piping `%>%` the output into another function or when set visible using `(`. In our case this would be the integer vector `1:28`.

```
(purrr::walk(1:28, ~ scrape_function(.x, api_key)))
```

Comment: Thanks again.  How would I do this if my function had a second argument of a different length?  I.E. api_key <- c("test1", "test2")

Comment: Do you want to loop every test2 over each test1? Then you would need to nest your map call for example: `map(1:10, ~ map2_chr(.x, letters[1:20], paste))` where `1:10` would be test1 and `letters[1:20]` would be test2.

Comment: No.  I want to loop 1:28 with test1, and then 1:28 with test2.  So if it was a URL it would look something like: url <- glue::glue("http://www.http://www.madeupurl.com/api/figures?"period={period}&response_format=JSON&api_key={api_key}")

Comment: Does this work? `purrr::map(1:28, ~ map2(.x, api_key, scrape_function))` and api_key is defined as `api_key <- c("test1", "test2")`.

Comment: Or if you do only have a few elements in api_key then you could also use walk and pipe it through, but this is not as efficient and rather an example of how `walk` could be used: `1:28 %>% 
  walk(~ scrape_function(.x, test1)) %>% 
  walk(~ scrape_function(.x, test2))`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't walk2 work?  something like: purrr::walk2(1:28, api_key, ~ scrape_function(.x, .y))

Comment: Because in `map2` and `walk2` `.x` and `.y` must have the same length.

Comment: Awesome!  Is there a way to show which element of the vector caused an error in the function?

Comment: Do you know the `possibly`, `safely` functions in `purrr`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200670/discussion-between-jazzmatazz-and-timteafan).